# Can `GET_LOCK` blocks infinite seconds in MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL's `GET_LOCK(str,timeout)` function be used to implement application locks or to simulate record locks.
If I want to wait infinite seconds, How can I call `GET_LOCK`?
Does `GET_LOCK('lock_name', -1)` work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes with `GET_LOCK('lock_name', -1)` you can wait wait infinite seconds. This is not documented and was buggy. It is still not documented but as per bug reports this feature is fixed on version 5.5 and up.

Reference: [GET_LOCK() timeout behaves differently on differing platforms](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56836)

PS: Use this feature carefully. As it is not documented the behaviour may change in a future version.

Comment: It seems to be documented now, but it's quite a misfeature. MariaDB does not support it at all. To be portable, just use a large timeout.